# From Node js Object, How would I know If I can use that object as a ReadSteam or WriteStream or both

Tags: node.js

I am very new to Node js. I came across below example.

```
var r = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
var z = zlib.createGzip();
var w = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt.gz');
r.pipe(z).pipe(w);
```

From Node js API documentation zlib.createGzip()  returns a Gzip object. How would I know that Gzip object can be used as a readstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's explained at the top of the documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib), though I agree that they could've repeated it in the class-specific paragraphs.